# Unable to run 'npm start' in Mac

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-start

I am trying to run the following command "npm start" however it throws the following error:

```
internal/net.js:17
    throw new RangeError('"port" argument must be >= 0 and < 65536');
    ^

RangeError: "port" argument must be >= 0 and < 65536
    at assertPort (internal/net.js:17:11)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1389:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/Users/keyurshah/fulljs/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/keyurshah/fulljs/server.js:10:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (/Users/keyurshah/fulljs/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/keyurshah/fulljs/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: You're using wrong port in `app.listen(...`, usually it's 3000.

Comment: @alexmac: Can you please suggest how do I set the port? I want to be it at 8080. I added 'var port={8080}' in my net.js file but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: It must be set in `app.listen` function, not just defined in variable.

Comment: @alexmac: I added 'app.listen(8080);' in my net.js file however I get the same error when I try to rerun 'npm start'. Do I need to set that command in my 'Server.js' file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `server.js` line 10. Your port is probably specified there.

If not just declare it to be what you want right before the listen function.

From

```
app.listen(port, ...)
```

to

```
app.listen(8080, ...)
```

Otherwise you haven't shown any code not sure how we could help you with such limited information...

I recommend you start with more simple projects and get a feeling for how things work: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Answer (score 0):

try to do this or change with any port number you like .listen(portNumber)

```
var http = require('http');
    http.createServer( function (request, response) { 
    //your code
    }).listen(8081);
```